# Login route to use custom guard when default guard is set to 'api'

Tags: php, laravel

I am about to start building a gateway app that will be communicating with mobile app users exclusively via api. The gateway app also has the moderator users which are separated in a different table as moderators will only be using web interface and not api, to manage mobile users. I have set up the default guard as:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

and the rest of the stuff there:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'moderators',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

     'moderators' => [
         'driver' => 'eloquent',
         'model' => 'App\Moderator::class',
     ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

   'moderators' => [
        'provider' => 'moderators',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 15,
    ],
],
```

Now, the issue is that even with other guards set up correctly, the login route is always trying to use the default guard, no matter what I do and returns an error when I try to log in as a moderator.

I have specified `$this->middleware('auth:web');` in controller, but it still uses default guard for login.

The idea is that mobile users will never be able to log in via web interface and only can communicate via api, and moderators will only use web guard and never api.

I could put default guard as 'web' and reverse the logic, but I still would like to know whether it is possible and how to make it work when default guard is set to 'api'.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using grouped routes -

Route::middleware(['auth:api'])

In case you have ungrouped routes -

$this->middleware('auth:web')

Comment: I have this `$this->middleware('auth:web')` and it still doesn't work. The login route seems to ALWAYS use the default guard which in this case I want to be 'api'

Comment: The web auth won't work for the api. You need to add api authentication packages like passport. OR You can create a new controller to validate user login and than you can set your route to the newly created controller's method

Comment: Default guard has to be 'api' but I want admins to use 'web' auth which as you can see is defined in my post. THe issue here is that login route for standard auth, always use the default guard defined and unless I change the default guard from api to web - it won't work. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I think I have found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816799/non-default-guard-is-being-ignored-in-laravel-5-5?rq=1